# Why it's not playing all the conversations and not in the right order from start to end?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

For testing I have two conversations at index 0 and 1.
And I want it to play the first conversation index 0 and then when it finish playing it to start playing the next conversation at index 1.

This is the script with the playing methods. The first should play a list/array of conversations one by one the second should play only a single conversation :

PlayConversations and PlayConversation.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEngine;

public class ConversationTrigger : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<Conversation> conversations = new List<Conversation>();
    public static List<int> conversationsToPlay = new List<int>();
    public bool conversationEnd;
    public GameObject canvas;
    public static int conversationIndex;

    private DialogueManager dialoguemanager;
    private string jsonPath;

    public void InitJsonPath()
    {
        jsonPath = Application.persistentDataPath + "/" + "Json.txt";
    }

    private void Start()
    {
        conversationIndex = 0;
        dialoguemanager = FindObjectOfType<DialogueManager>();
    }

    public IEnumerator PlayConversations()
    {
        canvas.SetActive(true);
        conversationEnd = false;
        var conversations = conversationsToPlay.ToArray(); // Copy the list
        conversationsToPlay.Clear(); // Immediately clear the original list

        for (int i = 0; i < conversations.Length; i++) // iterate over the array
        {
            // Now you also don't need to remove items anymore, 
            // since you already cleared the list
            yield return StartCoroutine(PlayConversation(conversations[i]));
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator PlayConversation(int index)
    {
        if (conversations.Count > 0 &&
            conversations[index].Dialogues.Count > 0)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < conversations[index].Dialogues.Count; i++)
            {
                if (dialoguemanager != null)
                {
                    dialoguemanager.StartDialogue(conversations[index].Dialogues[i]);
                }

                while (DialogueManager.dialogueEnded == false)
                {
                    yield return null;
                }
            }

            conversationEnd = true;
            conversationIndex = index;
            canvas.SetActive(false);
            Debug.Log("Conversation Ended");
        }
    }

    public void SaveConversations()
    {
        string jsonTransform = JsonHelper.ToJson(conversations.ToArray(), true);
        File.WriteAllText(jsonPath, jsonTransform);
    }

    public void LoadConversations()
    {
        string jsonTransform = File.ReadAllText(jsonPath);
        conversations.Clear();
        conversations.AddRange(JsonHelper.FromJson<Conversation>(jsonTransform));
    }
}
```

For that I made another helper script :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayConversations : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static ConversationTrigger conversationTrigger;
    private static PlayConversations instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        conversationTrigger = GetComponent<ConversationTrigger>();
        instance = this;
    }

    public static void ConversationToPlay(int index)
    {
        ConversationTrigger.conversationsToPlay.Add(index);
        instance.StartCoroutine(conversationTrigger.PlayConversations());
    }
}
```

And a script for testing :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BeginningCutscene : MonoBehaviour
{
    public DepthOfField dephOfField;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (dephOfField.dephOfFieldFinished == true)
        {
            PlayConversations.ConversationToPlay(0);
            PlayConversations.ConversationToPlay(1);
        }
    }
}
```

But it's start playing first the conversation at index 1 then only part of conversation at index 0 and then start over again then ending.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue has to do with the way you implemented the `ConversationsToPlay` method. At each call of the method you start a new coroutine which in turn will call the  `PlayConversation` method. What this means is that each call of `ConversationToPlay` will play the conversation at the index you passed and that is why they are overlapping.

The simplest solution I can think of is to move the start of the coroutine outside of the `ConversationsToPlay` method.

Something like this:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayConversations : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static ConversationTrigger conversationTrigger;
    private static PlayConversations instance;

    private void Awake()
    {
        conversationTrigger = GetComponent<ConversationTrigger>();
        instance = this;
    }

    public static void AddConversationToPlay(int index)
    {
        ConversationTrigger.conversationsToPlay.Add(index);
    }

    public static void StartPlayConversationsCoroutine()
    {
        instance.StartCoroutine(conversationTrigger.PlayConversations());
    }
}
```

and the test script

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class BeginningCutscene : MonoBehaviour
{
    public DepthOfField dephOfField;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (dephOfField.dephOfFieldFinished == true)
        {
            PlayConversations.AddConversationToPlay(0);
            PlayConversations.AddConversationToPlay(1);
            PlayConversations.StartPlayConversationsCoroutine();
        }
    }
}
```